# Integer representation to float representation

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point, ieee-754

Is there an algorithm that can convert a 32-bit integer in its integer representation to a IEEE 754  float representation by just using integer operations?

---

I have a couple of thoughts on this but none of these works so far. (Using C)

1. I was thinking about shifting the integers but then I failed to
   construct the new float representation on that .
2. I suppose I could convert the integer to binary but it has the same
       problem with the first approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert the integer to binary"?  It already is in binary...

Answer (score 2):

[excellent resource on float](http://www.fsinc.com/reference/html/com9anm.htm)

```
Address   +3        +2      +1      +0
Format SEEEEEEE EMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM
```

> S    represents the sign bit where 1 is negative and 0 is positive.
>
> E    is the two’s complement exponent with an offset of 127.
>
> M    is the 23-bit normalized mantissa. The highest bit is always 1
>   and, therefore, is not stored

Then look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for two's complement

---

**I'll use num as an array of bits, I know this isn't standard C array range accessing, but you get the point**
So for a basic algorithm, we start with filling out S.

```
bit S = 0;
if (num[0] ==1) {
  S = 1;
  num[1..32] = -num[1..32] + 1; //ignore the leading bit. flip all the bits then add 1
}
```

Now we have set S and we have a scalar value for the rest of the number.

Then we can position our number into the mantissa, by finding the first index of 1. Which will also let us find the exponent. Note here that the exponent will always be positive since we can't have fractional int values. (also, make a special case for checking if the value is 0 first, to avoid an infinite loop in here, or just modify the loop appropriately, I'm lazy)

```
int pos = 1;
signed byte E = 32;
bit[23] M;
while(num[pos] == 0) {
  --E;
  ++pos;
}
int finalPos = min(32, pos+23); //don't get too many bits
M = num[pos+1..finalPos]; //set the mantissa bits
```

Then you construct your float with the bits in S,E,M